# How to convert a Unicode text file in ANSI format using Java

Tags: java

I have one Text File abc.txt which is in Unicode format. I want to convert this into ANSI format. 
How to do this.

I have done google and got the following , but Its very lengthy to understand.

[Java- Converting from unicode to ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943781/java-converting-from-unicode-to-ansi)

Comment: Does your "ANSI" refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format)? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Alvin Wong - Thanks For Your Response. Anyway I have got one work around. I am opening the Text File using Pywinauto and Save as in ANSI formate. That is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a wild guess, because you're using [`pywinauto`](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), it means that the data you have is in the default win32 encoding format for unicode, which is to say, in UTF-16LE. There is **no such thing** as a file in unicode, the file is in an encoded representation of unicode.

To convert a file from UTF-16 to ASCII,you want to do:

```
unicode_data = open(filename).read().decode('utf-16le')
ascii = unicode_data.decode('ascii')
```